# Apache Spark Exception: FileAlreadyExistsException: Operation failed: "The specified path already exists."

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I’m facing errors while writing parquet data to some temporary folder in ADLS-GEN2.

My folder ‘X’ has parquet files Partitioned with YYYY MM DD sub folders. I have loaded entire data from ‘X’ folder to a dataframe and tried to write the data from dataframe to some temporary folder ‘y’ in ADLS gen2 using simple command below. But writing to folder ‘y’ is failing with below error. Any help/suggestions greatly appreciated .

*WriteCommand:*

```
Folder_x_df.write.mode("overwrite")      
.option("header","true")
.parquet(folder_y_path)
```

*Error:*

Job aborted.Caused by: Job aborted due to stage failure.Caused by: FileAlreadyExistsException: Operation failed: "The specified path already exists.", 409, PUT,https://adlsname.dfs.core.windows.net/............./y/part-00221-c0d1b33f-65f1-4474-a4c8-094df51599bd-c000.snappy.parquet?resource=file&timeout=90, PathAlreadyExists, "The specified path already exists. RequestId:5393b5b3-801f-0003-1da7-16cfb5000000 Time:2021-03-11T18:50:09.5444226Z". Caused by: AbfsRestOperationException....

I'm using cluster version: **6.4.x-scala2.11**

Completed Error Log:

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:601)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:26)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:176)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:178)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:180)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:182)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:184)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:186)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:188)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:190)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:192)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:194)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:196)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:198)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:200)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:202)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:204)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read.<init>(command-1978144014673122:206)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$.<init>(command-1978144014673122:210)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$.<clinit>(command-1978144014673122)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:714)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:667)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:396)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 136 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 136.3 in stage 6.0 (TID 166, 10.139.64.6, executor 2): org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: PUT, https://adlsname.dfs.core.windows.net/............./y/part-00136-360acd3f-6ae8-4e37-8dce-eb6b47bd0407-c000.snappy.parquet?resource=file&timeout=90
StatusCode=409
StatusDescription=The specified path already exists.
ErrorCode=PathAlreadyExists
ErrorMessage=The specified path already exists.
RequestId:24504b99-d01f-0094-639e-1500eb000000
Time:2021-03-10T11:10:42.1357194Z
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.checkException(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:946)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.create(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:224)
    at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FileSystemWithMetrics.create(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:291)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$create$1$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:544)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$create$1$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:541)
    at com.databricks.s3a.S3AExeceptionUtils$.convertAWSExceptionToJavaIOException(DatabricksStreamUtils.scala:108)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$create$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:541)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$create$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:541)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$withUserContextRecorded$1.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:936)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionContext(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionTags(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withUserContextRecorded(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:909)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$create$1.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:540)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$create$1.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:540)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$recordOperation$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:428)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionContext(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionTags(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:409)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.recordOperation(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.create(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:537)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystem.create(DatabricksFileSystem.scala:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:255)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:433)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:543)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: PUT, https://adlsname.dfs.core.windows.net/............./y/part-00136-360acd3f-6ae8-4e37-8dce-eb6b47bd0407-c000.snappy.parquet?resource=file&timeout=90
StatusCode=409
StatusDescription=The specified path already exists.
ErrorCode=PathAlreadyExists
ErrorMessage=The specified path already exists.
RequestId:24504b99-d01f-0094-639e-1500eb000000
Time:2021-03-10T11:10:42.1357194Z
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:134)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.createPath(AbfsClient.java:243)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.createFile(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:322)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.create(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:220)
    ... 49 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2362)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2350)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2582)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2529)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2517)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2282)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:711)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:601)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:26)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:176)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:178)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:180)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:182)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:184)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:186)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:188)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:190)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:192)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:194)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:196)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:198)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:200)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:202)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$$iw.<init>(command-1978144014673122:204)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read.<init>(command-1978144014673122:206)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$.<init>(command-1978144014673122:210)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$read$.<clinit>(command-1978144014673122)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at lined41e33c74e694199a189dffb81fc63f246.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:714)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:667)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:396)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Try checking your logs for earlier errors. This is probably happening because something failed before in the plan, and is being retried.

Comment: I don't this so. It has written the parquet files partially to the temporary folder and then failed.

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: @user3588007 what was the issue here? How did you solve this?